# Need to produce two pwm signals with 180 degree phase shift and different duty ratios, frequency of both are 50 kHz

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, power-electronics

A sample picture of how the output should be is given below(in figure top square pulse has 50 percent duty and bottom one has 60 percent duty, 50 kHz is frequency).

[image: required output]

Where should I start looking or which controller can be used to achieve this?
(Can I code these output directly?)(should I include more info?)

Comment: How would you control the duty of each? Are both totally independent?

Comment: How accurate do you need the 180 degree phase shift to be? What kind of resolution do you require for the duty factor?

Comment: @Andyaka  set duty in code, duty  are totally independent

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  Both pulses here should be having greater than or equal to 50% duty factor(no gap between them if one is place above other).  Is 9bit resolution possible?

Comment: 9-bit resolution should be possible if the processor's system clock is greater than 50MHz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any microcontroller with 2 independent PWM interfaces.

Program the hardware registers of the 2 interfaces in order to get the desired PWM period and Ton.

The values that you will program in the registers will depend on the clock frequency that drives the PWM interface.

---

Don't do it in software (delay loop). Use the hardware registers.

Comment: Can you suggest  a controller for me to learn.

Comment: Many microcontroller PWM peripherals will run multiple outputs off of one counter.  This lets you have two outputs in lock-step, but with different duty cycles.  This is particularly prevalent in peripherals designed to drive 3-phase motors.

Comment: Swagath: do you need a finished board ready to be programmed or you want to design your own board? Arduino board are off-the-shelf finished products.

Comment: @EnricoMigliore A finished board would be nice.